# PHP $_FILES empty with jquery generated input

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to upload some images with PHP. I am generating inputs with JQUERY like this:

```
    $( "#new" ).click(function() {
            $( ".upload-area" ).append( "<div><input type='file' name='image[]' class='input-file'></div>");
          });
          $("body").on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
            $(this).parent("div").remove();
        });
```

Form is generated with Codeigniter 3.

```
<form action="http://localhost/***********/index.php/admin/estate/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <?php echo form_input($in_title);?>
  <a class="btn btn-success" id="new">ADD</a>
  <div class="upload-area">
    <input type="file" name="image[]" class="input-file">
  </div>
</form>
```

But when I try to submit the form. This inputs wont show up in $_FILES.

I am sure that the generated inputs are between the form-tags. If I put in a static input, it will be submited.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your html

Comment: done an edit with the opening tag

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I tried it but there aren't any errors. With a static input there is no problem. Just with the generated by jquery.

Comment: just checked your code, and it works fine, possibly it's some environment configuration, have you checked if file upload is enabled? `file_uploads` directive in php.ini, also check the values of other directives as stated in [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads)

Comment: I just checked it and it's on :/

Comment: updated comment, please take a look

Comment: how are you submitting the form?